# Change src attribute if parent has a certain class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

so I have jQuery and HTML code like this

```js
if (!jQuery('ol li').hasClass('comment-author-someusername')) {
    jQuery(this).children('.avatar-wrapper img').addClass('changepic');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="children">
  <li class="comment byuser comment-author-someusername odd alt depth-2" id="comment-500">
    <div id="div-comment-500" class="comment-body">
      <div class="comment-meta">
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
          <div class="avatar-wrapper">
          <img alt="" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/92b6ba12f2a3d2532ec846a89598c663?s=80&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/92b6ba12f2a3d2532ec846a89598c663?s=160&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-80 photo" height="80" width="80"> 
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

What I want to achieve is that when the `li` does NOT have a class that starts with `comment-author-` then the img should get a class. Using that I can change the src-attribute for that pic but so far none of my different codes seems to work. Do you guys have any idea how to do that?

Comment: `.comment-list` where is the element with this class?

Comment: oh its not always there I will edit my code

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to tag `img`, you have `<           img alt=""` instead of `<img alt=""`

try:

```
if($(".comment-list .children>li").prop("class").indexOf("comment-author-") === -1) {
   jQuery(this).child('.avatar-wrapper img').addClass('changepic');
}
```

Comment: I corrected that thanks :) but still using that code I get an "undefined" in the console

Comment: Mean you didn't import jquery library !

Comment: this won't work fully as you would still get matching elements if the element had a class like `test-comment-author-test` and OP states class should start with `comment-author-`

Comment: added jquery library

Comment: and found out it must be children not child but still ..